# Product of $10$ consecutive integers can never be a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, square-numbers

This is a question from *Bosnia and Herzegovina mathematical Olympiad $2002$*.

There are already many similar questions, which I have done in the past.

[For $5$ consecutive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304417/product-of-5-consecutive-integers-cannot-be-perfect-square)

[A more general case for $3$ consecutive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266042/product-of-three-consecutive-positive-integers-is-never-a-perfect-power).

[For $6$ consecutive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90894/product-of-six-consecutive-integers-being-a-perfect-square)

And similar proves are available for $3$ (Which was once asked in Korean Mathematical Olympiad) and $4$ (Indian national mathematical Olympiad) consecutive integers.

I also know the general result which is [here](http://www.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1939-03.pdf) but I am no way going to use that in a competition.

Please try to give a high school argument as supposed to be given in a national Olympiad.

Thanks.

Comment: I am still thinking about a basic proof. Maybe this will help: Multiplying 10 consecutive numbers will result in a number with last digit 0. Multiplying any number with itself ($x^2$) will have the last digit 0, only if x has the last digit 0.

Comment: @P. Siehr Actually at least the last two digits will be $0$, but I am not sure it is a good approach to look only at the divisibility by $2$ and $5$

Answer (score 3):

Ah got it. [Here is a Wordpress article](https://projectpen.files.wordpress.com/2009/06/pen-a9-a37-o511.pdf)  which gives a proof which is not so simple but works fine at Olympiad level.

Comment: I was very close to solution $A9$ but before I could complete it you came up with  the article. But the other solutions are also very beautiful.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, did you use the same argument they are using? If not, then your answer will be gladly welcomed.

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra No, it's actually very similar, I don't want to post it. But I had something else in mind too, which I thought I could use differently. For example, consider the product of seven consecutive integers, which we can write as $(x-3)(x-2) (x-1)x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$. Now, expanding this out, and actually simplifying as a polynomial, we see this is equal to $x(x^2(x-7)^2 + 36)$. Now, if the product is a perfect square, then so is $x(x^2(x-7)^2 + 36)$. If $x$ is co - prime to $36$, then it's coprime to $x^2(x-7)^2 + 36$ as well. But then, each one will have to be a square.

Comment: So either $x$ is not co prime to $36$, or there are two squares differing by $36$, wherein we know all the possibilities. But the question is, what if $x$ isn't co prime. There I was stuck (in the seven case) before I changed approach to counting primes in the interval $(x,x+10)$. Feel free to add thoughts, but I think this is a stuck point, although the polynomial observation is useful.